# How to remove index column when getting latex string from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, latex

Originally, you could simply pass an argument in the `to_latex` method of the Pandas `DataFrame` object. Now you get a warning message about signature changes. Example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> import numpy as np

>>> data = {f'Column {i + 1}': np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, )) for i in range(5)}

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)

>>> df
   Column 1  Column 2  Column 3  Column 4  Column 5
0         1         8         3         3         5
1         8         6         7         7         3
2         2         1         6         1         1
3         9         7         9         5         5
4         5         4         7         8         9
5         9         5         3         6         2
6         6         9         9         6         8
7         8         7         2         6         5
8         4         9         4         6         2
9         2         6         5         3         0

>>> lat_og = df.to_latex(index=False)
<ipython-input-7-986346043a05>:1: FutureWarning: In future versions `DataFrame.to_latex` is expected to utilise the base implementation of `Styler.to_latex` for formatting and rendering. The arguments signature may therefore change. It is recommended instead to use `DataFrame.style.to_latex` which also contains additional functionality.
  lat_og = df.to_latex(index=False)

>>> print(lat_og)
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
\toprule
 Column 1 &  Column 2 &  Column 3 &  Column 4 &  Column 5 \\
\midrule
        1 &         8 &         3 &         3 &         5 \\
        8 &         6 &         7 &         7 &         3 \\
        2 &         1 &         6 &         1 &         1 \\
        9 &         7 &         9 &         5 &         5 \\
        5 &         4 &         7 &         8 &         9 \\
        9 &         5 &         3 &         6 &         2 \\
        6 &         9 &         9 &         6 &         8 \\
        8 &         7 &         2 &         6 &         5 \\
        4 &         9 &         4 &         6 &         2 \\
        2 &         6 &         5 &         3 &         0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

You get the desired output with no index column, but I don't want to have to keep using this if it will change, or if I have to continuously `import warnings` to fix it.

The warning message recommends we use the `style` attribute. How can I use the `style` attribute to ignore the index column? I read the documentation of the `to_latex` method associated with the `style` attribute, but it doesn't have the simple argument as above. Example:

```
>>> lat_new = df.style.to_latex(hrules=True)

>>> print(lat_new)
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
\toprule
 & Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 & Column 5 \\
\midrule
0 & 1 & 8 & 3 & 3 & 5 \\
1 & 8 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 3 \\
2 & 2 & 1 & 6 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 9 & 7 & 9 & 5 & 5 \\
4 & 5 & 4 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
5 & 9 & 5 & 3 & 6 & 2 \\
6 & 6 & 9 & 9 & 6 & 8 \\
7 & 8 & 7 & 2 & 6 & 5 \\
8 & 4 & 9 & 4 & 6 & 2 \\
9 & 2 & 6 & 5 & 3 & 0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

The index column is there in the LaTeX. What are some ways we can remove the index column without using the original method?

## Edit

If you come across this issue, know that the pandas developers are planning to deprecate the `DataFrame.to_latex()` method. They are currently in the process of using the `Styler.to_latex()` method instead. The signatures as of now are not the same and require additional methods for hiding the index column or escaping latex syntax. See [41649](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/41649) for more current updates on the process, and see [44411](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/44411) for the start of the rabbit hole. They plan on having this fixed in pandas 2.0.

Comment: An interesting question! There's no reference to this in the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html

Comment: There is also no `escape` argument like the original method has. What if I want to have latex in the column names? This new solution does not fully replace the original. @SNygard

Comment: @GabeMorris, to handle those cases I think it is possible to use the [format_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format_index.html) method (`df.style.format_index(axis=1, escape="latex")` is equal to use the old `df.to_latex(escape=True)`)

Comment: For more info, the `DataFrame.to_latex` method currently uses a Python parser which is out of date and no longer maintained, whilst the `Styler.to_latex` method uses a template parser which has many more features. Merging the two is quite difficult, but the `Styler.to_latex` method already allows all of the features of `DataFrame.to_latex` it just requires some re-engineering of code, some of the solutions are as described below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to use the [hide()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide.html) method of the `style` attribute of a Pandas dataframe. The following code will produce a LaTeX table without the values of the index:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {f'Column {i + 1}': np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, )) for i in range(5)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
lat_new = df.style.hide(axis="index").to_latex(hrules=True)
print(lat_new)
```

The result is the following:

```
\begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 & Column 5 \\
\midrule
2 & 5 & 9 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & 6 & 0 & 9 & 5 \\
3 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\
8 & 9 & 3 & 7 & 8 \\
5 & 9 & 7 & 4 & 4 \\
0 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 6 \\
5 & 7 & 7 & 8 & 6 \\
2 & 2 & 9 & 3 & 3 \\
6 & 0 & 0 & 9 & 2 \\
4 & 8 & 7 & 5 & 9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: I was just about to say something about this! Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know `to_latex` could be chained after `df.style`, very helpful!